# How to play a unique medielement in a ListView in XAML/Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a list of Audiofiles shown in a list view with a play/pause button for each listItem (containing individual MediaElements). The problem I face is that since there is no "IsPlaying" and the list is bound at runtime? How can I ensure that only one item is played? i.e., during audio play if user taps on some other item, it should ensure that the previously playing item is stopped forcibly.

Comment: Why don't you use a single MediaElement on the page, and bind it's source to the selected item in the list?

Comment: In that case I have to create the play/pause buttons separately on the list item and their handling. I am already handling the itemselected event where the user selects a particular audio file and navigates to the next page to play, but this current page acts as a preview page of all the audio files.